# MPAndroidChart: How to set different colors for labels in PieChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a `PieChart` in `MPAndroidChart` library with light and dark slices. Example is on picture:

[image]

As it seen by the image, I need labels to have different colors. How can I make it? I've tried to:

1. Use `pieDataSet.setValueTextColors(textColorsArray);` method, but it's actual for values text, not for labels.
2. Use `pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(someColor);`, but this method is able to set only one color for all labels.
3. Override PieChart class, but there is no such method like `getEntryLabelColor()` to override.

Please, give me an advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
legend.setCustom(colorArray, labelArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, because `legend.setCustom()` sets colors of _legend_ entries' squares, not colors of _labels_. I suppose, I have to implement custom chart labels.

Comment: @YamashiroRion use this, PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)